# Problems with scrollTo() in android

Tags: android, scroll, chat, scrollview, android-edittext

I´m developing an application which incorporates a chat and when a type a new message it stores it into a file in the internal memory.
Also, when i type a new message, it automatically scrolls to the bottom of the editText (where the messages are), and it works fine on the first try,but when i open the application again and it loads the history from the file, the automatic scrolling no longer works properly because, although scrolling to the bottom as well, it hides the last line of text.

Here is the .java file:

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity {

private static EditText messageHistory;
//
private EditText messageInput;
//
private Button sendButton;
//
private ScrollView scroller;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat);

    //Prevents the keyboard from appearing when not rquested
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    ProjectData.chatLogFile = new FileHandler(getApplicationContext(), ProjectData.CHAT_LOG_FILE);
    ProjectData.chatLogFile.create();

    getViews();

    getChatLog();

    addListennerOnButton();
}

/**
 * Finds all the views in this activity and stores them in global variables
 */
private void getViews ()
{
    messageHistory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageHistory);
    messageInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageInput);
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    scroller = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.historyScroller);
}

private void getChatLog ()
{
    messageHistory.setText(ProjectData.chatLogFile.getData());
    scroller.scrollTo(0, messageHistory.getBottom());
}

private void addListennerOnButton ()
{
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!messageInput.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                newMessage(messageInput.getText().toString(), 0);
                scroller.scrollTo(0, messageHistory.getBottom());
                messageInput.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void newMessage (final String msg, int id)
{
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    switch (id) {
        case 0: strBuilder.append("User:\n");break;
        case 1: strBuilder.append("PC Medic:\n");
        default: break;
    }

    strBuilder.append(msg + "\n");
    messageHistory.append(strBuilder.toString());
    messageHistory.refreshDrawableState();
    ProjectData.chatLogFile.addData(strBuilder.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuFAQ:
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), FAQActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menuConfig:
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), PrefActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menuAbout:
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menuExit:
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundService.class);
            stopService(intent);
            setResult(ProjectData.EXIT_CODE);
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

and the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/chatMainLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoChat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_top"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo" />


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/historyScroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageHistory"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:editable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</ScrollView>

<EditText 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:focusable="true" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatBottomLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageInput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:maxHeight="60dp"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/messageInput"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/messageInput"
        android:hint="@string/message_input"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        style="@style/textInput" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="@string/send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone see or even understand the problem, please?

Thanks in advance,

Ricardo Amendoeira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sana's answer allowed me to solve my own problem. I think you need to allow the TextView to recalculate window bounds, so try wrapping your scrollTo() method in a post [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

See my code below:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            scrollView.scrollTo(0, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually was able to solve it that way (sorry for not posting it :S). Here's my code:
`chatScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

  @Override

  public void run() {

    chatScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

      }

    }, 200L);`

Comment: @RicardoAmendoeira This `delay` solution is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is laying out your view. When you layout your view in the onCreate method it hasn't fully inflated and it works proper in scrolling out to the first line, hence you might want to put your method `getChatLog();` in

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  getChatLog();
 }
```

Let me know if it works on not.

This is a very interesting question.

Comment: Thanks! unfornatunately I will only be able to test it tomorrow, but I´ll let you know if it works!

Comment: I just tested it and it's not working for me....Is there any way to force the onWindowFocusChanged method to be called? Because it is only being called next to onCreate....Also I've put scroller.scrollTo(0, messageHistory.getBottom()); in the method as well..any further help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does messageHistory.getBottom() return you the bottom row position?

Comment: I'm not sure...how can i verify that?

Comment: But possibly it does, because on the first try it works properly...it´s only when I close the application and open it again that it shows this problem...

Comment: In your application before closing it, I guess your onResume() method is being called and not the onCreate() method. Can you look at once what is the order of the methods being called? Or else try calling finish() before closing the app.

Comment: I've been around with this and still can't figure it out...Started using fullScroll(ScrollView.FPCUS_DOWN) instead of scrollTo(0, messageHistory.getBottom()) but the problem still maintains..I think the problem is that when appending a new message, it needs to do something, but i can't figure what it is...Also after appending a message I can't scroll down to see message, I just see "User:", but after I click the editText below (used to write the message), I can scroll down and view the message...